# Scheduling pods onto nodes only af kube2iam is up and running

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam

On our AWS based Kubernetes cluster, we use kube2iam to provide pod level IAM roles.

There's an edge case we're dealing with where pods load before kube2iam is ready and they get the default instance role, and are therefore unable to operate.

I can think of a few solution which I dislike:

- Requiring app code to check it's own role
- Adding an init container to check that the expected role is being served
- Adding podAffinity to each pod to make sure it's co-located with a running kube2iam instance

I don't want each application developer to need to remember to include some specific machinery to ensure they get a role.

Is there a way to globally do this? I'm guessing it would involve something like marking the Node as unschedulable by default and changing that status when kube2iam is up. Not sure how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

How about utilizing liveness probe inside your Pod templates against Pod created by kube2iam`s DaemonSet ? It should keep restarting newly created pods until kube2iam is ready.
(e.g HTTP probe against 8181 port - default listening port of kube2iam)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i dont want developers to need to remember to add some liveness check to each deployment. i want the cluster to guarantee it

Comment: Ok, I see. I found also another interesting feature of Kubernetes that might suit your needs, it`s called init-containers.

Comment: Here is an excerpt from official documentation which gives an idea on what Init Containers can be used:
_They run to completion before any app Containers start, whereas app - Containers run in parallel, so Init Containers provide an easy way to block or delay the startup of app Containers until some set of preconditions are met._


https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

Comment: thanks for the comment! as mentioned in the OP im  aware of the init pod option. i'm looking for something where developers adding new deployments dont need to remember to add them, but instead the platform (k8s cluster) enforces this for them.

Comment: Please take a look at Istio`s Injection Webhook sidecar. maybe this is a solution for you (appends sidecar containers to each pod’s template spec during creation time) 
https://istio.io/help/ops/setup/injection/

Comment: @nepomucan, thats a great idea. i've actually started to look at this in the last few days and it appears to be exactly what we need. incidentally, there's a good piece on medium about how to pull this off: https://medium.com/dowjones/how-did-that-sidecar-get-there-4dcd73f1a0a4